# Decomposition of the spectrum of a closed Banach subalgebra

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces, operator-algebras, banach-algebras

In the book *An Introduction to Operator Algebras* by  Kehe Zhu the following theorem is stated:

**Theorem.** Suppose $A$ is a closed subalgebra of a unital Banach algebra $B$ with $\hat{1}\in A$. If $x \in A$, then $\sigma_A(x)$ is the union of $\sigma_B(x)$ and some (possibly none) bounded connected components of $\mathbb{C}-\sigma_B(x)$; being $\sigma_A(x)$ the spectrum of $x$ in the Banach algebra $A$ and similarly with $\sigma_B(x)$.

The proof is based on the following fact (which is stated right before the theorem): Suppose  $U,V \subset \mathbb{C}$ are open sets such that $U \subset V$ and $\partial U \cap V =\emptyset$.  Then $U$ is the union of certain connected components of $V$.

Once said that, in the proof of the theorem it is proven that the open sets $U:=\sigma_A(x)^C$ and $V:=\sigma_B(x)^C$ satisfy the conditions of the above claim. Therefore, $U$ is the union of certain components of $V$.

**Why does this imply the conclusion of the theorem?**

First of all, if $\sigma_A(x)=\sigma_B(x)$ then we are done ( $\sigma_A(x)$ is the union of $\sigma_B(x)$ and none bounded components of $\sigma_B(x)^C$). Let's suppose that $\sigma_B(x) \subsetneqq \sigma_A(x)$, according to the statement, I have to show that if $V=\cup_{i\in I}V_i$, with $V_i$ the connected components of $V$ then
$$
\sigma_A(x)=\sigma_B(x) \bigcup \left( \bigcup_{j\in J}{V_j} \right) 
$$
with $J\subset I$ and each $V_j$ bounded. I had the following idea: we can write $\sigma_A(x)=\sigma_B(x) \cup \left( \sigma_A(x)-\sigma_B(x) \right)$ and $\left( \sigma_A(x)-\sigma_B(x) \right) \subset V$. Now, let $V_i$ be a connected component of $V$ such that $V_i \cap \sigma_A(x) \neq \emptyset$. Then $V_i \cap \sigma_A(x)$ is a closed set in $V$, therefore if I could prove that $V_i \cap \sigma_A(x)$ is also an open set in $V$ then $V_i \subset V_i \cap \sigma_A(x)$ (since $V_i \cap \sigma_A(x)$ would be both: a closed set and an open set in $V$) and thus $V_i= V_i \cap \sigma_A(x)$; therefore we would have that the equation $\sigma_A(x)=\sigma_B(x) \cup \left( \cup_{j\in J}{V_j} \right) $ holds.

However, I don't see why  $V_i \cap \sigma_A(x)$ would be an open set in $V$. Maybe my idea is just wrong.

Any suggestion in order to conclude the proof?

If I made any errors in my reasoning I would also appreciate any corrections.

In advance thank you.

Comment: You need to show that the boundary of $\sigma_A(x)$ is contained in $\sigma_B(x).$ Then the result follows.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc isn't possible that for instance $\sigma_A(x)=\overline{B_2(0)}$ and  $\sigma_B(x)=\overline{B_1(0)}$?  In which case $\partial \sigma_A(x)$ isn't contained in $\sigma_B(x)$.

Comment: It is not possible. We always have that $\partial \sigma_A(x)\subset \sigma_B(x).$ In your particular example it is even simpler: the spectral radius of $x$ in $B$  is equal $1$. But the spectral radius does not depend on the algebra so it cannot be equal $2$ in $A.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc you're right, thank you very much for the correction and for the hint!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think we can complete the proof as follows:

Let $V_i$ a connected component of $V$ such that $\sigma_A(x) \cap V_i \neq \emptyset$. Then
$$
\sigma_A(x) \cap V_i =V_i \cap \left( \sigma_A(x)-\sigma_B(x) \right)
$$
As the user @RyszardSzwarc well said in the comments, we have that $\partial \sigma_A(x) \subset \sigma_B(x)$ and therefore $\sigma_A(x)-\sigma_B(x)=(\partial \sigma_A(x) \cup \sigma_A(x)^{\circ})-\sigma_B(x) =\sigma_A(x)^{\circ}-\sigma_B(x)=\sigma_A(x)^{\circ} \cap \sigma_B(x)^C$ which is an open set, thus we can write $\sigma_A(x) \cap V_i$  as an intersection of open sets. This completes the proof of the theorem.

**Edit:** It's probably good idea including to proof of $\partial \sigma_A(x) \subset \sigma_B(x)$. One way  of proving this fact (probably not the optimal/easiest/elegant way) is as follows:

We can use the fact that $C$ is a unital Banach algebra and $(x_n) \subset C$ a sequence of invertible elements  which converges to a noninvertible element $x \in C$, then $\lVert (x_n)^{-1} \rVert \rightarrow \infty$. Bearing this in mind,let $\lambda \in \partial \sigma_A(x)$, if $\lambda \notin \sigma_B(x)$ then $x-\lambda \hat{1}$ is an invertible element in $B$ but not in $A$. Since $\lambda \in \partial \sigma_A(x) $ we can find a sequence $(\lambda_n)$ such that $x-\lambda_n \hat{1}$ is an invertible element in $A$ but $x-\lambda_n \hat{1} \rightarrow x-\lambda \hat{1}$.

By the above claim, we would have that $\lVert \left( x-\lambda_n \hat{1} \right)^{-1} \rVert  \rightarrow \infty$. On the other hand, if $G(B)$ is the set of invertible elements in $B$, then it's a known fact that the map $f:G(B) \longrightarrow G(B), y \mapsto y^{-1}$ is continuous and therefore $\lVert f(x-\lambda_n \hat{1}) \rVert \rightarrow  \lVert f(x-\lambda \hat{1}) \rVert =\lVert  \left( x-\lambda \hat{1} \right)^{-1}\rVert < \infty $. This condradiction shows that we must have $\partial \sigma_A(x) \subset \sigma_B(x)$.